# What is the equivalent of .loc with multiple conditions in R?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I wonder if there is any equivalent of .loc in R where I am able to have multiple condition that would work in a for loop.

In python I accomplished this using .loc as seen in the code below. However, I am unable to reproduce this in R.

```
for column in df.columns[1:9]:
    for i in range(4,len(df)):
        col = 'AC' + str(column[-1])
        df[col][i] = df['yw_lagged'].loc[(df['id'] == df[column][i]) & (df['yearweek'] == df['yearweek'][i])]
```

In R, I thought this would work

```
df[i,col] <- df[df$id == df[column][i] & df$yearweek == df$yearweek[i], "yw_lagged"]
```

but it dont seem to filter in the same way as .loc does.

edit:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 6, 7, 1, 2), v1 = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
1), v2 = c(6, 3, 2, 2, 6, 3), v3 = c(7, 6, 5, 3, 7, 6), v4 = 
c(NA, 7, 7, 6, NA, 7), v5 = c(NA, 8, 14, 8, NA, 8), v6 = c(NA, 
NA,15, 15, NA, NA), v7 = c(NA, NA, 16, 16, NA, NA), v8 = c(NA, 
NA,NA, 17, NA, NA), violent = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), yw_lagged = 
c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 0), yearweek = c(20161, 20161, 20161, 20161, 
20162, 20162), AC1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AC2 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), AC3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AC4 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), AC5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AC6 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AC7 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), AC8 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[Picture of expected output (Tried to add some connections using colors)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15Dp4.png)

Comment: Can you share sample data? Please post the output from `dput(head(df))` in a code block. Thanks!

Comment: (It would help to have the expected output as well, at least 1-2 columns of such. Thanks!)

Comment: @r2evans added both dput(head(df)) and a picture of my expected output. I tried use some colors to see the connections between the coloumns.

Comment: The `id` field looks like it is not unique. When one finds (say) `2` in another column for a lookup within `id`, why do we know to choose the first and not the second instance of `id == 2`?

Comment: @r2evans Thats why I need the second condition saying df$yearweek == df$yearweek[i]. With both the "id" condition and the "yearweek" condition we end up with one value. As with the python code. However, this does not seem to work in R?

Comment: okay, I see now; are you by chance already using either dplyr or data.table? This is easily a grouping operation, and those R "dialects" make it a little bit easier; if not, base-R is likely fine

Comment: @r2evans Yes I am actually using both earlier in the project. How would you go about the problem using grouping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample data is lacking any matches, so I'll override a few rows of `yw_lagged`:

```r
df$yw_lagged[1:4] <- 1:4
```

From here,

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(yearweek) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^v[0-9]+"),
                ~ yw_lagged[match(., id)],
                .names = "AC{sub('^v', '', .col)}")) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 × 20
#      id    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8 violent yw_lagged yearweek   AC1   AC2   AC3   AC4   AC5   AC6   AC7   AC8
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     2     6     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA       1         1    20161     2     3     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2     2     1     3     6     7     8    NA    NA    NA       0         2    20161     1    NA     3     4    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 3     6     1     2     5     7    14    15    16    NA       1         3    20161     1     2    NA     4    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 4     7     1     2     3     6     8    15    16    17       0         4    20161     1     2    NA     3    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 5     1     2     6     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA       0         1    20162     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 6     2     1     3     6     7     8    NA    NA    NA       0         0    20162     1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
cols <- grep("v[0-9]+", names(df), value = TRUE)
data.table(df)[, (sub("^v", "AC", cols)) :=
                   lapply(.SD, \(z) yw_lagged[match(z, id)]),
               .SDcols = cols][]
#       id    v1    v2    v3    v4    v5    v6    v7    v8 violent yw_lagged yearweek   AC1   AC2   AC3   AC4   AC5   AC6   AC7   AC8
#    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>   <num>     <num>    <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
# 1:     1     2     6     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA       1         1    20161     2     3     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2:     2     1     3     6     7     8    NA    NA    NA       0         2    20161     1    NA     3     4    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 3:     6     1     2     5     7    14    15    16    NA       1         3    20161     1     2    NA     4    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 4:     7     1     2     3     6     8    15    16    17       0         4    20161     1     2    NA     3    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 5:     1     2     6     7    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA       0         1    20162     2     3     4    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 6:     2     1     3     6     7     8    NA    NA    NA       0         0    20162     1    NA     3     4    NA    NA    NA    NA
```